# modelling a differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

I have a system of ODEs with a pathogen population $(P)$ being modelled as a logistic growth as,
${dP\over dt}=rP(1-{P\over k})$, where $r$ is the replication rate and $k$ is the carrying capacity term and both these parameters are constant values.

Now I want to introduce antibiotic effect so that the antibiotic will inhibit the growth of pathogen.For this I am planning on introducing a constant $\alpha \in (0,1)$ so that the replication will be reduced as $\alpha r$. But I want this replication to depend on the antibiotic concentration. So if I model the system as,

${dP\over dt}=\alpha A rP(1-{P\over k})\\
{dA\over dt}=-dA$
where $A$ is the antibiotic concentration, will this be right? ($d$ is the antibiotic decay rate)

Or, should this be,

${dP\over dt}= \alpha {1\over A} rP(1-{P\over k})\\
{dA\over dt}=-dA$

as, when $A$ is high the replication should be reduced more (because the antibiotic will be more effective at high concentrations), and as $A$ decreases the reduction in the replication will be less?

Out of these two systems which one maps this relationship correctly or is there any other way to model this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT :

$${dP\over dt}=\alpha A rP(1-{P\over k})$$
$${dA\over dt}=-DA$$

Solving the separable ODE ${dA\over dt}=-DA$ leads to 
$$A=c_1e^{-Dt}$$

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\alpha c_1e^{-Dt} rP(1-\frac{P}{k})$$

Again this is a separable ODE :
$$\frac{k\:dP}{P(k-P)}=\alpha c_1re^{-Dt} dt$$
$$k\int \frac{dP}{P(k-P)}=\alpha c_1r\int e^{-Dt} dt$$
$$\ln\left|\frac{P}{k-P}\right|=-\frac{\alpha c_1r}{D}e^{-Dt}+c_2$$
$$\frac{P}{k-P}=c_3\exp\left(-\frac{\alpha c_1r}{D}e^{-Dt}\right)$$
Then you can solve it for $P$.

Compute the $c_1$ and $c_3$ according to the initial conditions.

On the same way, in case of 
$${dP\over dt}=\alpha \frac{1}{A} rP(1-{P\over k})$$
$${dA\over dt}=-DA$$
the result is :
$$\frac{P}{k-P}=c'_3\exp\left(\frac{\alpha r}{c'_1D}e^{Dt}\right)$$
Then solve it for $P$.

Compute the $c'_1$ and $c'_3$ according to the initial conditions.

Now, compare the behaviour of the two functions $P(t)$ and determine which one is convenient for the model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, what I don't understand is whether  ${dP\over dt}=\alpha A rP(1-{P\over k})$ or modelling it as  ${dP\over dt}= \alpha {1\over A} rP(1-{P\over k})$ is better?

Comment: I was still editing my answer. Now it's finished.

Comment: Thank you. So, I can use both forms, its a matter of what best matches the model?

Comment: If I well understand, your problem is not mathematical, but physical, that is choosing the convenient form for the model. Try both and see which one is the best.